# Centos server not sending mail

Tags: linux, centos, postfix-mta

I am trying to send mail from my centOS server but it is not sending. I have been trying to to do all what I know but it did not work. Anybody has a solution ?
There is the output of /var/log/maillog

```
Aug 23 04:35:01 ip-148-66-128-46 sendmail[15264]: NOQUEUE: SYSERR(panopta-agent): can not chdir(/var/spool/mqueue/): Permission denied
Aug 23 05:36:01 ip-148-66-128-46 sendmail[19114]: NOQUEUE: SYSERR(panopta-agent): can not chdir(/var/spool/mqueue/): Permission denied
Aug 23 06:36:01 ip-148-66-128-46 sendmail[22828]: NOQUEUE: SYSERR(panopta-agent): can not chdir(/var/spool/mqueue/): Permission denied
Aug 23 07:36:02 ip-148-66-128-46 sendmail[26535]: NOQUEUE: SYSERR(panopta-agent): can not chdir(/var/spool/mqueue/): Permission denied
Aug 23 08:37:01 ip-148-66-128-46 sendmail[30302]: NOQUEUE: SYSERR(panopta-agent): can not chdir(/var/spool/mqueue/): Permission denied
Aug 23 09:37:02 ip-148-66-128-46 sendmail[1563]: NOQUEUE: SYSERR(panopta-agent): can not chdir(/var/spool/mqueue/): Permission denied
Aug 23 10:38:01 ip-148-66-128-46 sendmail[5428]: NOQUEUE: SYSERR(panopta-agent): can not chdir(/var/spool/mqueue/): Permission denied
Aug 23 11:38:02 ip-148-66-128-46 sendmail[9137]: NOQUEUE: SYSERR(panopta-agent): can not chdir(/var/spool/mqueue/): Permission denied
Aug 23 12:39:01 ip-148-66-128-46 sendmail[12902]: NOQUEUE: SYSERR(panopta-agent): can not chdir(/var/spool/mqueue/): Permission denied
Aug 23 13:39:01 ip-148-66-128-46 sendmail[16658]: NOQUEUE: SYSERR(panopta-agent): can not chdir(/var/spool/mqueue/): Permission denied
Aug 23 14:40:02 ip-148-66-128-46 sendmail[20434]: NOQUEUE: SYSERR(panopta-agent): can not chdir(/var/spool/mqueue/): Permission denied
Aug 23 15:41:01 ip-148-66-128-46 sendmail[24203]: NOQUEUE: SYSERR(panopta-agent): can not chdir(/var/spool/mqueue/): Permission denied
Aug 23 16:41:01 ip-148-66-128-46 sendmail[28150]: NOQUEUE: SYSERR(panopta-agent): can not chdir(/var/spool/mqueue/): Permission denied
Aug 23 17:41:02 ip-148-66-128-46 sendmail[31963]: NOQUEUE: SYSERR(panopta-agent): can not chdir(/var/spool/mqueue/): Permission denied
Aug 23 18:42:01 ip-148-66-128-46 sendmail[3299]: NOQUEUE: SYSERR(panopta-agent): can not chdir(/var/spool/mqueue/): Permission denied
Aug 23 19:43:01 ip-148-66-128-46 sendmail[7120]: NOQUEUE: SYSERR(panopta-agent): can not chdir(/var/spool/mqueue/): Permission denied
Aug 23 20:43:02 ip-148-66-128-46 sendmail[10828]: NOQUEUE: SYSERR(panopta-agent): can not chdir(/var/spool/mqueue/): Permission denied
Aug 23 21:43:02 ip-148-66-128-46 sendmail[14604]: NOQUEUE: SYSERR(panopta-agent): can not chdir(/var/spool/mqueue/): Permission denied
Aug 23 22:44:02 ip-148-66-128-46 sendmail[18455]: NOQUEUE: SYSERR(panopta-agent): can not chdir(/var/spool/mqueue/): Permission denied
Aug 23 23:45:01 ip-148-66-128-46 sendmail[22309]: NOQUEUE: SYSERR(panopta-agent): can not chdir(/var/spool/mqueue/): Permission denied
Aug 24 00:45:02 ip-148-66-128-46 sendmail[26113]: NOQUEUE: SYSERR(panopta-agent): can not chdir(/var/spool/mqueue/): Permission denied
Aug 24 01:46:01 ip-148-66-128-46 sendmail[29973]: NOQUEUE: SYSERR(panopta-agent): can not chdir(/var/spool/mqueue/): Permission denied
Aug 24 02:46:02 ip-148-66-128-46 sendmail[1321]: NOQUEUE: SYSERR(panopta-agent): can not chdir(/var/spool/mqueue/): Permission denied
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try "sudo chmod 755 /var/spool/mqueue"

Comment: chmod: cannot access ‘/var/spool/mqueue’: No such file or directory

Comment: edit sendmail.cf file and set "QueueDirectory=/var/spool/mqueue/q*"   and that restart sendmail service

Comment: please give me the directory of that file.